# How to prevent an app redirect on iOS for an URL with query?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

we're troubleshooting a problematic scenario involving the Universal Links on iOS.
In a nutshell, we need to make sure the app redirect happens only for the path without a query.
I.e. when the user goes to https://www.example.com/path, we want it to be redirected to an app. However, we have a bunch of complex scripts on the site, triggered by urls like https://www.example.com/path?someparam=1&anotherparam=23, that should be handled via the **browser **(no support for those features in the app yet).
We've have our Domain Association file uploaded, and it has featured the following snippet in the components section:

```
{"/":"/path"},
```

This does force the iOS to redirect to our app whenever user clicks a no-query an any application, or scans a QR code.
However, it does also cause a redirect for the links with query (https://www.example.com/path?someparam=1&anotherparam=23)

I've read through the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks on this, and have tried a few tricks:

1. Insert an exclude block prior to the existing one:

```
{"/":"/path", "?":"?*", "exclude":true},
{"/":"/path"},
```

2. Update the existing block to enforce an empty query on it:

```
{"/":"/path", "?":""}, // supposed to override the implied "?":"*"
```

3. Prepend the existing block with a bit different form of the query pattern (to intercept a specfic param in query):

```
{"/":"/path", "?":{"someparam":"?*"}, "exclude":true},
{"/":"/path"},
```

Nothing did help so far - iOS still does redirect the links https://www.example.com/path?someparam=1&anotherparam=23 to the application. I have checked that the file is not cached by our reverse proxy. I have checked that the old file is not being cached by our cloudflare CDN. I have checked that the old file is not being cached by the apple delivery service. I have got a clean iOS device to ensure I don't have the redirect preference cached localy - still redirects.

Is this scenario supported at all? Maybe there is a bug in iOS/Safari implementation?

Comment: Try `{"?":"*","exclude":true}`

Comment: It did work! Damn, it contradicts the Apple docs (it is supposed to cover ANY queries, including the empty ones. But actually it doesn't get triggered until i add something after the trailing ? in the url).